# Is auto increment id possible for UseInMemoryDatabase?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I use UseInMemoryDatabase in my .net core application. I need auto increment functionality.  Is that possible? For example my class is;

```
public class City
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

...

```
public DbSet<Statistic> Statistics { get; set; }
```

...

I want to add a new object as follows;

```
context.Cities.Add(new City{Name = "Amsterdam"});
```

And i don't want to add as follows;

```
context.Cities.Add(new City{Id = 1,Name = "Amsterdam"});
```

Because I don't want to check existing ids every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible and even the default behaviour as long as you don't set the Id (so it is inserted with Id `0`) which is the same behaviour as in DB-backed providers.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace InMemoryIdSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CityContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase("Cities").Options;
            using (var context = new CityContext(options))
            {
                context.Add(new City { Name = "Vienna" });
                context.Add(new City { Name = "Munich" });
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var context = new CityContext(options))
            {
                foreach(var city in context.Cities)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"City {city.Id}: {city.Name}");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class City
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class CityContext : DbContext
    {
        public CityContext(DbContextOptions<CityContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
$ dotnet run
City 1: Vienna
City 2: Munich
```